# Finding Conditional Probability of Poisson Process, Markov Chains

Tags: probability, markov-chains, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Consider a Poisson process {X(t), t ≥ 0} with constant rate λ > 0. Let X(a, b) denote the number of events in the time interval a < t ≤ b, and 0 < t1 < t2 < t3 are three given time points.

Let given integers k1 ≥ 0, k2 ≥ 0, k3 ≥ 0 and n ≥ 1 satify the relationship k1 + k2 + k3 = n. Find the the conditional probability of {X(0, t1) = k1, X(t1, t2) = k2, X(t2, t3) = k3} given {X(0, t3) = n}, that is,

P{X(0, t1) = k1, X(t1, t2) = k2, X(t2, t3) = k3 | X(0, t3) = n} .

i think im making it more difficult than it needs to be but if i could get some help on how to go about it i would be grateful

Comment: Your question is a good one, but because you have not put MathJax into it, people are having trouble reading it. Look up the MathJax tutorial (it is easy!) and edit your question to make it more readable. Also look up similar questions on "Poisson processes" on the site and see if any of them answers your question or gives you a hint, in which case this question can be removed also.

Comment: just directly apply the definition of conditional probability. Note that if event $E$ implies another event $F$, then $E \subseteq F$ and thus $E \cap F = E$. Then with independent increment we are done.

Answer (score 1):

We know $k_1, k_2, k_3 \ge 0$ i.e $k_1,k_2,k_3 \in N$ $\cup$ {0}.

By using the definition of conditional probability $$P(A | B) = \frac {P(A, B)}{P(B)}$$

on the you're given we get 
$$
\frac{P(X(0, t_1) = k_1, X(t_1, t_2) = k_2, X(t_2, t_3) = k_3, X(0, t_3) = n)}{P(X(0, t_3) = n)}
$$

If we use **Lack of Memory** property we can simplify the top probability since we know $n = k_1 + k_2 + k_3$. Hence, 
$$
\{ X(0, t_1) = k_1, X(t_1, t_2) = k_2, X(t_2, t_3) = k_3, X(0, t_3) = n \} 
= \{ X(0, t_1) = k_1, X(t_1, t_2) = k_2, X(t_2, t_3) = k_3\}
$$

Now, once we have the **Lack of Memory** applied on the set, we can enforce the property on the probability as well,

$$
P\{ X(0, t_1) = k_1, X(t_1, t_2) = k_2, X(t_2, t_3) = k_3, X(0, t_3) = n \} 
= P\{ X(0, t_1) = k_1, X(t_1, t_2) = k_2, X(t_2, t_3) = k_3\}
$$

At this point, you have a solid ground from which you can continue, i.e

$$
\frac{P(X(0, t_1) = k_1, X(t_1, t_2) = k_2, X(t_2, t_3) = k_3)}{P(X(0, t_3) = n)}
$$

Next hint would be to show independence of the random variables using the fact that the intervals (0, $t_1$) (0, $t_2$) and (0, $t_3$) do not overlap. Applying independece on the aforementioned probability you get something similar to this,

$$
\frac{P(X(0, t_1) = k_1) \cdot P(X(t_1, t_2) = k_2) \cdot P(X(t_2, t_3) = k_3)}{P(X(0, t_3) = n)}
$$

Last step that should be applied you know from the following fact,

$$
X(a,b) \text{~} Poisson(\lambda \cdot(b-a)) 
$$

Using the PDF of Poisson Distribution you have your answer.